# Trigger a jenkins build when remote jenkins job has finished

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-plugins, remote-server

I have jenkins installed on two different servers `s1` (where I can see the status of the projects but where I can not modify nor add any item) and `s2` where I have full control of Jenkins and of the server.

I have a project in Jenkins in `s2` that I would like to execute when a specific build on `s1` has finished (with success).

I know I could use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin) in s1 and from there trigger a job in `s2`, but I will have to ask someone with the required permissions to do it for me.

I wonder if there is any way I can monitor the job in `s1` (to which I have read access) from `s2` and trigger my project when the build is successful. Can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the [URLTrigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin).

Please install this plugin on the s2 server.

On your s2 job, choose the "[URLTrigger] - Poll with a URL" build trigger with some settings like below:

[image]

You can check the following status:
lastBuild, lastStableBuild, lastSuccessfulBuild, lastFailedBuild, lastUnstableBuild, lastUnsuccessfulBuild, lastCompletedBuild.

For each status, you can get the build number for example by adding /buildNumber.

Example: .../lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber will return 4 (build #4)

[image]

The plugin will calculate a MD5 with this build number. Every hour, the triggerURL plugin will have a look to the URL.
If the MD5 changes, it will trigger a build.

It should do the job :)

Comment: thanks Bruno! I'll install it tomorrow and vote your answer if I manage to make it work!

Comment: OK, please keep me informed :)

Comment: Hi Bruno, so I installed the plugin but now I have a few questions (that I think should be included in the answer..): first of all, where can I find doc about the possible values like lastSuccessfulBuild etc? second from your screenshot it seems like I need to know the buildNumber, but this is likely to change every time... shouldn't I use "check the status" instead?

Comment: also.. I can check every hour, but is there a way to tell jenkins that once I trigger the job because the build on s1 was successful to only check from the following day?

Comment: I've added some information. It should be easier to understand how the plugin is working. You don't need to know the build number. So when the S1 build is OK, it will generate a new "successful" build number (4 --> 5). The MD5 will change and the triggerURL plugin will launch a new S2 build (just one time).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97388/discussion-between-lucacerone-and-bruno-lavit).